# how access to items in nested structure in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, object, struct

```
public struct psample
{
  public double[,] F1;
  public double[,] F2;
  public double[,] F3;
  public double[,] F4;
};


public struct P_F
{
   public psample persamp = new psample();
};
```

I create the object :

```
P_F pf = new P_F();
List<P_F> pfet = new List<P_F>();
```

but how can I access to F1, F2, F3,F4  ??
The goal would be to access the data like this:
  pfet[0].persamp[1].F1[,]

Answer (score 1):

> but how can I access to F1, F2, F3,F4 ?? The goal would be to access the data like this: pfet[0].persamp[1].F1[,]

Let's break down that assignment

```
pfet[0]
```

You can do that, as long as you have assigned at least one element to that list.

```
persamp[1]
```

It is incorrect to use [] because persamp is not an array and does not have an indexer.

```
F1[,]
```

Assuming you have assigned an appropriate array to F1 (etc), you can access the array itself as `F1` or elements of that array by specifying appropriate indices e.g. `F1[0, 1]`.

So assuming you have appropriately initialized your data structure, you could so something like

```
double val = pfet[0].persamp.F1[0,1]
```

Comment: I want to use persamp[1] as an array and   have indexer

Comment: Where is your indexer? It's not in the code you posted.

Comment: I do not know how i make indexer for  persamp